# Cache from $resource service with specific querys

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching

I'm extending `$resource` with some methods, which using `query`, just for example:

```
var Resource = $resource(url, {}, {
  query: {
    cache: true
  }
})

Resource.getByCategory = function (categoryId) {
  return Resource.query({ categoryId: categoryId })
}

Resource.getBySearch = function (text) {
  return Resource.query({ search: text })
}
```

I want to cache only the data which comes from `getByCategory`. as you can see, both methods use `query`, so I cannot define in the `query` configuration level - as I'm doing now and the data is cached for the both methods.

Any ideas? I thought about somehow using decorator for cached methods, not sure if it is going to help.

Comment: Have you tried defining these methods this way: `var Resource = $resource(url, {}, { getByCategory: { method: 'GET', cache: true, isArray: true }, { getBySearch: { method: 'GET', isArray: true } );`

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work.